# i have a roomba 4220 and looking for ros node

Tags: ros, roomba, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can the roomba 4200 series work with CREATE ROS OR ROOMBA 530
I REMOVE THE vacuum motors and stuff and look at the create.py and look might work
but has any tried it or what changes to make it work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12603/i-have-a-roomba-4220-and-looking-for-ros-node/) by [robotmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1631/robotmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

its seems that they have same ROI so - yes (but create has some additional commands).

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0